# javascript: storing multiple variables in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 4 functions: `function1`, `function2`, `function3`, `function4`.

Now, a value is being calculated in each of the first 3 functions. I want to store these 3 values in a global array and use it in the 4th function.

Is the following approach correct?

```
var array1=[]

function1(){
array1[0]=calculated value1;
}

function2(){
array1[1]=calculated value2;
}

function3(){
array1[2]=calculated value3;
}
```

This array will be used in the 4th function.

Comment: Do you have any issue or you're just asking for a *better* way to do stuff?

Comment: Dang! My apologies !!
Yeah. So I want to confirm if my approach is correct.
and If there is a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

No, I would not recommend doing it like that.

**Update**:
Based on information you wrote as a comment to another answer, I guess that your different functions are used to calculate some value based on user input.

If you really want to cache the values in a global variable, I would still suggest that you use an object with named members, since it usually makes more sense than a numeric index when reading and trying to understand the code:

```
var myGlobalObject={};

function one(){
  myGlobalObject.nameOfValueOne = calculated value1;
}
```

If you need it as an array when you plot it, your can create that array:

```
myPlotFunction( [ myGlobalObject.nameOfValueOne, myGlobalObject.nameOfValueTwo] );
```

But if it doesn't make sense to name the values, like if the user can add a variable amount of values, then you should use an array and probably use `myArray.push(value)`.

Comment: his functions are not returning anything!!

Comment: The array generated is being used as a dataset for creating a bar graph in d3.
I won't be able to use an object in that case. 
It has to be in an array.

Comment: @Reddy I'm aware that the pseudo code didn't have return statements. Cerberus didn't even write that the results should be added. I wanted to know why the most common approach wasn't used.

Comment: @some I totally agree, No offense just wanted to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT use global variables unless its very very necessary, And if at all you really want to use it try to use closures just to make sure you dont populate the global scope, Also to make your variables and functions private, So that other global variable and functions with the same name does not affect each other.

Try wrapping up your existing code in a closure. This way I think your existing code is not bad at all. And your global variable is global within the closure block.

```
 (function($){
  //.. your existing code.
 })(jQuery)
```

**Note:** All the variables and functions are available with in the closure block only.

Comment: This sounds good!
I hadn't thought about this.!
thank you. :)

Comment: What has jQuery to do with this????

Comment: Since he said d3 charts, he has to use Jquery for sure. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since functions are first class objects in JavaScript, you may do some hacky stuff like this

```
var i = 0;
var fa = function() {
  fa.result = "result_" + i;
  i += 1;
};

console.log(fa.result); // prints undefined

// now call fa
fa();

console.log(fa.result); // prints result_0


// now call fa again
fa();

console.log(fa.result); // prints result_1
```

So now each function stores it's own last result, which you may use in other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer related to your D3.js scenario, enjoy

```
// create a datastructure to hold your array like this
var ArrayHolder = function() {
  var _array = [null, null, null];
  var __nameIndexMap__ = {
    "A": 0,
    "B": 1,
    "C": 2
  };
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'setData', { 
    value: function(name, value) {
      var index = __nameIndexMap__[name];
      if (index >= 0) {
        _array[index] = value;
      }
    }
  });
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'array', {
    get: function() {
      return _array;
    }
  });
};

var myArray = new ArrayHolder();


console.log(myArray.array); // prints [null, null, null]

var i = 0;

function a() {
  // provide each function a name
  var __name__ = "A";
  myArray.setData(__name__, i++);
}

a();

console.log(myArray.array);  // prints [0, null, null]

function b() {
  var __name__ = "B";
  myArray.setData(__name__, i++);
}

b();

console.log(myArray.array); // prints [0, 1, null]

function c() {
  var __name__ = "C";
  myArray.setData(__name__, i++);
}

c();
console.log(myArray.array); // prints [0, 1, 2]


a();
console.log(myArray.array); // prints [3, 1, 2]
```